# How can $k$ a field be a $\frac{k[x]}{x^n}$-module?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

From the definition of an $R$-module $M$ on Wikipedia, one of the conditions is that we must have an operation 
$$ \cdot : R \times M \rightarrow M $$
satisfying some particular properties.

If $k$ can be considered as a $\frac{k[x]}{x^n}$-module, I don't understand how we can have 
$$ \cdot : \frac{k[x]}{x^n} \times k \rightarrow k \qquad \qquad (*)$$
For example, $x \cdot \lambda = \lambda x \in \frac{k[x]}{x^n}$ as opposed to $\in k$.

Or is this a case of having to define a particular way in which the ring acts on $M$, i.e. declaring that in $(*)$, we only act using the degree zero elements of $\frac{k[x]}{x^n}$?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, $\cdot$ is not necessarily the usual multiplication; so you have to define a specific way in which the ring acts on $M$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The map $\cdot$ in this case is
$$
f \cdot \lambda = f(0)\lambda
$$
where $f \in k[x]/x^n$ and $\lambda \in k$.